# Associating/keeping track of Celery tasks

Tags: flask, celery

I've created an internal tool (developed in flask) for our company that allows my colleagues to restart and redeploy our applications.  When a user clicks on the Redeploy or Restart buttons, a celery task is spawned that does all the work in the background.

[image]

For example, when the Restart button is clicked, my app: 1) hits an API endpoint which starts the celery task; 2) using jquery, I replace the buttons with "Restarting app..." text; and 2) add a `data-id=` element to the corresponding application  tag so that the app can continually poll the celery worker so it can report when it's complete.

This all works great for the user that clicks the buttons.  But, when a second user opens the page in their browser, they are unaware that an application has been restarted because I don't yet store/associate the celery task ID with the application.  This brings me to my question, is there a best practice for associating the two?  I'm leaning towards creating a `celery_task_id` field in my applications model and adding the new celery task id when a task starts and removing it when the task has ended.  Is this a good approach?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.